# Clarifications regarding my ban

Tags: support, post-ban

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What can I do when getting “Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-sorry-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers)

Can someone please let me know why I am question banned?

I did not delete a question, and one of my questions was closed as a duplicate.

Anyone have any hints on how I can remove the ban?

Comment: Do you have any deleted answers?

Comment: No I don't. (How can I check ?)

Comment: If you have no deleted posts, the only thing I can see is a shared IP. Do you have a shared IP?

Comment: @DanJurgen you can't. You should just know.

Comment: @DanJurgen: not that you know of or none that you can see? You cannot see deleted posts; have any of your posts in the past been deleted at all because they were closed? Or by yourself?

Comment: Yes, that is possible. (our ISP might be using shared IPs.. not sure though.. but high probability)

Comment: @amanaPlanaCAnalPAnaMA Tab-completion fail.

Comment: Haha @DanielFischer I see that now :-P

Comment: @DanielFischer, yes there is possibility I might have deleted a question.

Answer (score 20):

You asked a question, *"How do I implement online photo albums on android?"* that got three downvotes and was closed by five community members.  Then you decided to re-ask the same identical question the next day, which also got three downvotes and was closed by five community members.

Both questions were deleted by the Community ♦ user one month later, on January 5, as part of Stack Overflow's automated culling process.  That's probably when the question ban took effect.

The specific details of the automated ban are kept secret to prevent gaming.  More info here: [What can I do when getting "We are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997)

Comment: For reference, the deleted questions are [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13725598/how-to-read-an-entire-remote-photo-album-android) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13709625/how-implement-online-photo-albums-on-android). They were asked (and closed) on December 4 and 5, 2012, then deleted by Community exactly one month later. The auto-deletion script might be getting a little more aggressive than I remember.

Comment: So I can not ask a question again ?

Comment: You know, there is one thing I don't understand. That is, why a valid meta post like this get's so heavily downvoted. From this I get the impression that people at SO don't want to discuss how the site is being run.

Comment: @tohecz: Everyone who is banned is referred to [this post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-sorry-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers), where the ban (and what to do about it) is described in detail. Anyone that is asking why they have been banned hasn't bothered to read it.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Then just close this, but why down-vote? I don't see any other reason then show the person: Nobody really wants you here, we will demotivate you as much as we can. Which is an approach that I can't accept.

Comment: @tohecz: [Downvotes work differently on Meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#vote-differences).

Comment: @RobertHarvey Yeah, that's the schizophrenia of MSO: Downvotes "expressing opinion" and having reputation system :-/

Comment: @tohecz What's interesting, is that I asked a [similar question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/167888/210573) and I was upvoted 20 or so times... Wonder what the difference is?

Comment: @xxmbabanexx: The difference is that you put some effort into that question.